# Update by query - Data refresh in following queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

When using `elasticsearch_dsl` to perform `UpdateByQuery` that is followed by a subsequent `GET` query that obtains the updated documents. The documents that are retrieved may contain 'stale' data - The data prior to the update.

How can I perform the update by query and ensure 'fresh' data? Is there a way to user `?refresh=true`? With `UpdateBuQuery` (`elasticsearch_dsl` helper class) or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.extra(refresh=True)`](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/update_by_query.html#extra-properties-and-parameters).

Comment: Does this really work?